# How would i detect when a key is being held in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keypress, onkeydown

currently when detecting if a key is held using `.keypress` in jquery, it detects as if the key is being typed into an input field, as it inputs one key, waits a short while, then fires the keys rapidly (the desirable outcome)

https://jsfiddle.net/pk2dLxuy/1/ is my fiddle

```
$(document).keypress(function(keydetect) {
if(keydetect.which == 119) {
       console.log("w")
       $("div").css("marginTop","-=10")
    }
if(keydetect.which == 97) {
       console.log("a")
             $("div").css("marginLeft","-=10")
    }
if(keydetect.which == 115) {
       console.log("s")
       $("div").css("marginTop","+=10")
    }
if(keydetect.which == 100) {
       console.log("d")
       $("div").css("marginLeft","+=10")
    }
}); //this is the bulk of the code, the other html and css dont really matter
```

currently the red square moves in relation to keys if they were being typed in a feild, how would i make it so it is always moving when a key is down?

an example of where this is seen is at https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/131423/index.html where you can test your keyboard buttons, and when you press and hold a key, it responds all the time, not just after a second of holding.

i am aware of the fact that this couldve been done with a different programming language, but this is just to show the idea of the desirable effect.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: *currently the red square moves in relation to keys if they were being typed in a feild*....but there is no field in the HTML to type!!!

Comment: Mamun i am aware of this, i am just saying that when it moves (each time the keys direction is logged to the console) it behaves like if you go into an empty notepad document and hold a key, it types 1 key, then types multiple very quickly until you stop holding the key. edit:spelling

Comment: Jack  i think it is made clear in the post that it is in relation to the wasd keys, the direction and speed doesnt matter, just how it moves, it ramps up in speed, whilst i'd like it to stay consistent

Comment: I'd suggest  you to register _keydowns/keyups_ to an object by listening the corresponding events, and then reading that registry object in a timed function loop like [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: Here is a working example https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390083/8291949